# Django : User models with different roles

Tags: python, django

I started to learn build class model using Django.

Before I create any class model.py, I want to know whether admin user (created thru py manage.py createsuperuser) can give permission to other users.

My project is building a cinema booking system and there are 4 different user types with different users.

For example, as a staff, I want to create a movie session.

This user story can be implemented by giving a permission to staff to create a cinema session by admin?

I am not sure whether I need to create user models by :

1. model.py on landing page
   OR
2. customize'User' with AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser

Please let me know whether I can just build class model at model.py
or customize user .....

hope my explanation is clear to you all..

Comment: Django already has groups and permissions, so it might be possible that you can work with the existing logic.

Comment: Thx! I will start working on model.py at core app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can implement your user story like that. After creating a new user in Django Admin Panel, you can provide different permissions to users or define groups and assign users to groups if you have some users with the same authority. Find more in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

[image: Django Admin User Info Page]

There exist two different solutions for you.

1. Extend Django's default User Model by inheriting your customized user from it and performing what you want. By using this approach, you can benefit from Django's default authentication and authorization system (see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)).
2. Substituting a custom user model and handling authentication, authorization, and all related features yourself (see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)).

Finally, reading this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/) is highly recommended for more details.

Good Luck.